# Apache and mod_expires

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

I have modified the setting in httpd.conf of Apache to be able to use mod_expires but when I load a page, now I have an error 500 (The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.).

In httpd.conf I really have : LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so without # before.

I use XAMPP on Windows Vista.

Is there something else that require to be activate?

The Apache server give webpages without problem when the .htaccess is empty. But I add the code following, I have the error 500.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800 #12 hours cache
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The contents of your error log could be instructive.

Comment: .htaccess: ExpiresDefault takes one argument, an expiry date code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1- Cannot add ExpiresDefault A604800 #12 hours cache because the #12 is not a comment... comments seem to be in 1 line.

2- I required to load the LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so too!

Thanks to point me out about checking the Log womble.